# Trying to getting the minimum & maximum size of two values in CSS3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, image-size

I am trying to set an image of my phone's width using Ionic4, but when I get my phone to landscape mode, I need it to use the height instead. So basically using the minimum size, and also need the opposite function for another place (maximum).

I tried using min() and max() function but apparently, it didn't work, I searched for it, and someone said that it got deprecated. (I don't mind deferent approach if any)

```
.heart-style {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: min(10vw, 10vh);
 height: min(10vw, 10vh);
}

.welcome-card ion-img {
 height: max(30vh, 30vw);
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

This is what I get when I try min() or max() functions:

---

Failed to compile.

./src/app/home/home.page.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Incompatible units: 'vh' and 'vw'.

---

and I tried deferent units as well, but the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@media (orientation: ...)` mediaqueries to detect wheter youre on `landscape` (which means the viewports `width` is greater then the `height`) or on `portrait` (which means the viewports `width` is **equal or less** then the `height`).

```css
.heart-style {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:10vw;
  height:10vw;
}

.welcome-card ion-img {
  height: 30vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  /* 1vw is > 1vh now */
  .heart-style {
    width:10vh;
    height:10vh;
  }

  .welcome-card ion-img {
    height:30vw;
  }
}

/* just for debugging */
.heart-style {
  background: blue;
}
.welcome-card ion-img {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart-style">
  heart
</div>

<div class="welcome-card">
  <ion-img>
    img
  </ion-img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to install ionic plugin `ionic-native/screen-orientation` it gives the flexibility of detecting screen orientation inside JS code and many other options too.

```html
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }

...


// get current
console.log(this.screenOrientation.type); // logs the current orientation, example: 'landscape'
```

this is official URL 
[native/screen-orientation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation)

Comment: I guess this can work as well, but it requires more work than the CSS solution. Thanks anyway.